# Eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I have two questions:

1. Windows has an Eclipse, the same way Linux has an Eclipse.
   If I develop a plugin for eclipse on windows will that one work on Linux? or I have to develop different versions for each?
2. Does the Eclipse framework differs for different types of eclipses?
   Eg: I have developed a plugin for Eclipse Europa, Now will that work on Eclipse Galileo? or the framework differs for Europa and Galileo?

Answer (score 1):

1 - Yes it will work.

Eclipse provides OS specific functionality for its supported OSes in the form of plug-in fragments, and the correct one is loaded depending on the detected running OS. If you are simply building a plug-in for anyone using Eclipse you should be fine.

If you were shipping your own set of plug-ins in an Eclipe RCP you'd have to ensure that the fragments for the OSes you wanted to support were all present.

2 - It depends what APIs you use and if they have changed, they should only be broken [when the major version changes](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Version_Numbering#When_to_change_the_major_segment). So Europa -> Galileo ->Helios should be fine.

Comment: Your number 2 is not always true.  The APIs can change when the minor version changes.  You should always check the "Migrating to Eclipse 3.y from 3.x" section of the documentation, found in the Platform Plug-in Developer Guide.